# Absolutely positioned div

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JBA</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
            #layout {
              float: left;
            }
            #title {
              padding: 10px; 
              border: 1px solid #ccc; 
              position: relative;
            }
            #content {
              position: absolute;
              top: 26px;
              left: 0;
              right: 0;
              bottom: 0;
              border: 1px solid #ccc; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="layout">
            <label id="title">Below is content:</label>
            <div id="content">
            </div> 
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
    </script>
</html>
```

What I need is to position #content div right below the #title label. However, float and position settings shouldn't be changed. So, how to calculate #content's top? 26px seems to work for Chrome but, for IE it needs to be 28px. Why?

Answer (score 0):

give position relative to the "#layout" div

```
#layout {
  float: left;
  position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it in chromium as well as IE9. For both position top: 28 is working properly. Screenshot is attached.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting something like this [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/9xVdA/)

some changes in your CSS :

```
       body {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
            #layout {
              float: left;
            }
     #title {
              padding: 5px; 
              border: 1px solid #ccc; 
              float:left;
            }
   #content {
              clear:both;
              width:400px;
              height:400px;
              border: 1px solid #ccc; 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set padding and margin to 0 on #content since browsers render this differently (Even though it´s not set).